# Using 'loop' causes infinite loop

Tags: assembly

I'm just trying to simplest loop for assembly, and for the first four loops, it seems to work fine. But after the first four loops, it goes into an infinite loop.

```
.data
    loop_count1 DWORD 4

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, loop_count1
loop11:
    loop loop11 
call dumpmem
call crlf
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Anyone know why?

**EDIT:** sorry, the loop wasn't the problem after all. calling dumpmem seems to be the problem, but I've used the same thing in other programs before, so I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Maybe you change the value of loop_count1 somewhere (directly or indirectly). It would be better if you show more code.

Comment: oh god, I'm so sorry, it wasn't the lines in the sample I put created in the question at all. These two lines are causing the problems, though I'm still not sure why. Sorry for mistaking the cause of the problem.

    call dumpmem
    call crlf

Answer (score 1):

It's a very old time when I saw assembler, so I can't give you professional answer :) I think that ecx after the loop becomes equal to 0. And it's quite possible that dumpmem can not accpet register ecx to be zero. Just for testing purposes you can add a line `mov ecx, 1` just before the call of dumpmem. Still infinite loop?

Comment: adding that line stopped the infinite loop, thank you. I should probably have asked my teacher about the details before. thanks!